# Configure EHCache with Spring and Hibernate, using multiple cache managers

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache

(first of all, sorry for my english ... I don't speak it very well)

Hi, 
I'm developing a multi-module web app using spring framework in version 4.0.9. I have three different jar modules containing three different entity models wired to its own database each other. These three models are using Hibernate in version 4.3.5 and spring too.

I want to configure Ehcache as hibernate's second level cache on each of one jar model modules and likewise I need to configure Ehcache for cache provider at principal webapp project.

- model-1.jar (spring + hibernate + ehcache), with hibernate-ehcache dependency version 4.3.5
- model-2.jar (spring + hibernate + ehcache), with hibernate-ehcache dependency version 4.3.5
- model-3.jar (spring + hibernate + ehcache), with hibernate-ehcache dependency version 4.3.5
- webapp.war (spring-mvc + ehcache), with spring-context-support 4.0.9 version dependency

In model-1 module something like this:

*(model-1-spring-context.xml)*

```
<bean id="oneSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="oneDataSource" />
 <property name="hibernateProperties">
 <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
  <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
  <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">one-ehcache.xml</prop>
 </props>

 </property>
 <property name="packagesToScan" value="......" />
 </bean>
```

*(one-ehcache.xml)*

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../config/ehcache.xsd"  name="oneHibernateCache">


    <diskStore path="/tmp/xxxx"/>

    <defaultCache 
            maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="120"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            overflowToDisk="true"
            maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
            diskPersistent="false"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            />
</ehcache>
```

model-2 and model-3 with analogous structure to model-1.

And webapp configuration something like this:

*(class configuration)*

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());

    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factory = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("web-ehcache.xml"));
        factory.setShared(true);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

*(web-cache.xml)*

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" name="webSpringCache">


 <diskStore path="/tmp/zzzzz" />

 <defaultCache 
 maxElementsInMemory="1" 
 eternal="true"
            overflowToDisk="false" 
            diskPersistent="false"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="1800" 
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="FIFO">
    </defaultCache>
```

I'm having several problems with cache managers, cache names and regions inside them. Spring context doesn't start ok and I don't know how to configure properly the modules.

I'd very pleased if somebody could help me.

Thanks a lot to everybody.

Comment: If you don't tell us what areexactly  the problems, we can't help you.